# GroupBy LINQ Query

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following structure of classes:

```
public partial class OrderOrderData
{
    public OrderOrderDataOfferOrder[] OfferOrder{get;set}
}

public partial class OrderOrderDataOfferOrder
{
    public OrderOrderDataOfferOrderQuestion[] Question{get;set}
}

public partial class OrderOrderDataOfferOrderQuestion
{
    public OrderOrderDataOfferOrderQuestionPrice Price{get;set;}
}
```

Now I am trying to retrieve that OfferOrder whose Question.Price is not equal to null.

For Example I have Object A, B and C in OfferOrder. Question.Price of C is not equal to null hence my LINQ query should return OfferOrder `C` to `pricedOfferOrder` .

I tried to do it by GroupBy but found no luck. I'm trying something like this but still clueless as to how will I get to the Price after grouping by `Question`

```
OrderOrderData OrderData = order;
OfferOrder pricedOfferOrder = OrderData.OfferOrder.GroupBy(x=>x.Question)...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple Where method is sufficient here:

```
OrderOrderData OrderData = order;

OfferOrder pricedOfferOrder = OrderData.OfferOrder
  .Where(d => d.Question.Any(e => e.Price != null));
```

Comment: I get `object reference not set to an instance of an object` when `Price` is null for all `Question`. How can I avoid this?

Comment: This can't happen! Are you querying against IQuerable or it is just linq to object?

Comment: My bad I'm actually doing this `OfferOrder pricedOfferOrder = OrderData.OfferOrder .Where(d => d.Question.Any(e => e.Price != null)).FirstOrDefault().Question)`

Comment: Ok so that is the reason if Price is null for all then `OfferOrder pricedOfferOrder = OrderData.OfferOrder .Where(d => d.Question.Any(e => e.Price != null)).FirstOrDefault()` will return nulll and accessing its property Question on null will result in null reference exception.

Comment: Any shorthand method, LINQ method to avoid this?

Comment: People had already given anser to your question that you recently posted here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/44491968/1505865

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any need to use `GroupBy` in this case. You could try something like this:

```
var offerOrder = OrderData.OfferOrder
  .FirstOrDefault(oo => oo.Question.FirstOrDefault(q=>q.Price != null) != null );
```

Essentially we use the `FirstOrDefault` method, which takes a predicate and provided that there is at least one item that fulfills this predicate this is the result of the query. Otherwise the default value is returned, which in out case is `null`. So we are looking for the first OfferOrder if there is any at all, whose `Question` array contains at least one `Question` (not null), whose `Price` is not null.

For further info regarding this method, please have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @JenishRabadiya Correct ! Thanks