# Object not set to an instance of an object when using Any()

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following LINQ

```
OfferOrder pricedOfferOrder = OrderData.OfferOrder
  .Where(d => d.Question.Any(e => e.Price != null)).FirstOrDefault().Question);
```

It works fine but when `Price` of all `Question` are null it throws the following Exception:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

My classes look like this:

```
public partial class OrderOrderData
{
    public OrderOrderDataOfferOrder[] OfferOrder{get;set}
}

public partial class OrderOrderDataOfferOrder
{
    public OrderOrderDataOfferOrderQuestion[] Question{get;set}
}

public partial class OrderOrderDataOfferOrderQuestion
{
    public OrderOrderDataOfferOrderQuestionPrice Price{get;set;}
}
```

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that you are using C# 6, you could make use of the [null conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators):

```
OfferOrder pricedOfferOrder = OrderData.OfferOrder
                                       .Where(d => d.Question?.Any(e => e.Price != null) ?? false)
                                       .FirstOrDefault()?.Question;
```

The problem's root is at the `d.Question.Any...` and at the `FirstOrDefault().Question`. If `d.Question` is null there isn't any meaning on calling `Any`. Furthermore, `FirstOrDefault` returns null if no element found. So you can't read property `Question` of null.

**Update**

If you use a previous version of C# (where LINQ apparently is available) , you could try the following:

```
OfferOrder pricedOfferOrder = OrderData.OfferOrder
                                       .Where(d => d.Question != null =>
                                                   ? d.Question.Any(e => e.Price != null) 
                                                   : false)
                                       .FirstOrDefault();
var question = pricedOfferOrder !=null ? pricedOfferOrder.Question : null;
```

Comment: this will be work with `C#` 6.0 or higher

Comment: @DarshanPatel of course. If OP meets any problem I suppose that he would mention it here.

Comment: according to the question "It works fine but when Price of all Question are null" I think the problem is only in FirstOrDefault only

Comment: @jitender The code as it is has problem also at `Any`. I don't think that we should take for granted that `Question` is always not null.

Comment: @Christos yup your are right I was thinking about the current problem only

Answer (score 0):

If you are using c#6 Or above

```
OfferOrder pricedOfferOrder = OrderData.OfferOrder
  .Where(d => d.Question.Any(e => e.Price != null)).FirstOrDefault()?.Question);
```

For older version

```
var data = OrderData.OfferOrder
  .Where(d => d.Question.Any(e => e.Price != null)).FirstOrDefault();
OfferOrder pricedOfferOrder = data != null ? data.Question : null;
```